# Plot Two Panda Dataframes That Have Different Index Types

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two dataframes...

One with an Integer index:

```
Date     Close
1  1998-01-02  1.000000
2  1998-01-05  1.002082
...          ...       ...
5511  2019-11-26  3.220914
5512  2019-11-27  3.234360

[5513 rows x 2 columns]
```

And another that looks like it uses the date value as the index:

```
Close
1998-01-02  1.000000
1998-01-05  1.002082
...          ...
2019-11-26  3.220914
2019-11-27  3.234360

[5513 rows x 1 columns
```

How do I plot them against each other?

Comment: To clarify, you want to plot the Close value over the Date?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: For both sets of data, on one graph. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Make a 'Date' column for the second DataFrame using:

```
df2['Date']=df2.index
```

Then reset the index of this DataFrame using:

```
df2=df2.reset_index()
```

Now, the two dataframes have the same indices, and have 
"Date" and "Close" columns so you could plot them in similar way.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Initialize exampe dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date": ["1998-01-02", "1998-01-05", "2019-11-26", "2019-11-27"],
    "Close": [1.000000, 1.002082, 3.220914, 3.234360],
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    index=["2000-01-02", "2002-01-05", "2015-11-26", "2017-11-27"],
    data={"Close": [1.000000, 1.502082, 2.220914, 3.034360]},
)

# Convert date strings to `datetime` objects
df1["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Date"])
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index)

# Create plot
plt.plot(df1["Date"], df1["Close"], df2.index, df2["Close"])
plt.show()
```

give as result:

[image]